# как поставить пароль на архив через shutil.make_archive

Tags: python, shutil

как мне поставить пароль на архив, который cоздаётся через shutil.make_archive

вот на это мне нужно поставить пароль

```py
def zipping():    
    d = randint(1, 88005353535) # название файла

    chars = 'abcdefghyjklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    chars += chars.upper()
    nums = str(1234567890)
    chars += nums
    special_chars = '$'
    chars += special_chars
    length = 50
    password = "".join(random.sample(chars, length)) # вот переменая где генерируется пароль

    shutil.make_archive(str(d),'zip', root_dir=str(ZipPATH["RootFolder"]))
```

Comment: я заранее извиняюсь если я создал вопрос который уже решили, но по крайней мере я сам не нашёл ответа

Comment: @Clark Devlin можете сказать как мне создать архив с паролем на библиотеке zipfile, буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Обманул вас, в `zipfile` такой функции нет, зато есть в библиотеке `pyminizip`.
Для установки: `pip3 install pyminizip`

На сколько я знаю именно папку добавить нельзя, но можно несколько файлов

```py
import pyminizip

compression_level = 5 # значение от 1 до 9, означает степень сжатия
pyminizip.compress("src.txt", "dst.zip", "password", compression_level) # для одного файла

pyminizip.compress_multiple([u'pyminizip.so', 'file2.txt'], [u'/path_for_file1', u'/path_for_file2'], "file.zip", "1233", compression_level) # для нескольких файлов
```

Comment: шяс проверю работает ли

Comment: а можно добавить не файл, а папку, тобиш мне нужно добавить в архив папку с файлами а не файл

Comment: @ВааАаа обновил ответ

Comment: а мне именно папка нужна, сейчас скину того, что мне нужно архивировать https://imgur.com/a/ed3Md56

Comment: блииин , ну как??? @Clark Devlin

Comment: @ВааАаа именно с паролем нельзя будет архивировать папку.